# How to append input type file and pass a file to it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an input type file it's id is "icon" and it can be repeated many times.
So i have a button when i click on it
 it will append a new input type file and i need to send the uploaded file from "icon" input to this new input with Jquery 
here is my code

```
<input type="file" class="chooseFile" accept="image/*" id="icon">
<button type="button"  id="add_item">add item</button>
<div id="appended_inputs"></div>
```

and here is jquery code

```
$('#add_item').click(function(){
   $('#appended_inputs').append(
       `<input type="file" id="new_icon"`>
   );
   $('#new_icon').val($('#icon').val());
});
```

Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that you will have multiple elements with the same ID.

Try use this code, it might be what you want:

```
$('#add_item').click(function() {
  $('#appended_inputs').append('<input type="file" class="new_icon" >');
  $('.new_icon:last').get(0).files= $('#icon').get(0).files;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#add_item').click(function() {
  $('#appended_inputs').append('<input type="file" class="new_icon" >');
  $('.new_icon:last').get(0).files= $('#icon').get(0).files;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="chooseFile" accept="image/*" id="icon">
<button type="button" id="add_item">add item</button>
<div id="appended_inputs"></div>
```

Comment: it's just an example but actullay i give each appended input a different id and name

Comment: @Doksh If you don't show us the correct code, then its very hard to provide you with a correct solution

Comment: thanks so much for your advice and sorry for this mistake . and thanks for help my problem was solved :)